# How to add python to tomcat 9 list of environment variables?

Tags: python, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a spring boot application that runs certain python scripts using the process class combined with the buffered reader to read the out put. This project works fin within the intellij tomcat embedded server. However when we try to run it on a stand alone tomcat server we get the error  *Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified* . Keep in mind this program works fine within the intellij embedded tomcat server. We have come tot he conclusion that THE stand alone tomcat is not picking up our python environment variables. How can we resolve this problem? Is there anything we need to add to tomcat to get the server to recongnize the python environment variable.

Comment: Where are those scripts located, are they in the classpath?

Comment: The scripts are located in the C:/python_scripts. Remember the scripts run fine from within the intellij ide when they are executed by the spring program. Its just that for some reason tomcat will not recongnize python as a system variable.

Comment: The fact that things run in the IDE doesn't mean a thing. In the IDE things aren't read from a jar/war (it isn't packaged, it is run from the build/target directory). Classloading / loading can change considerably when running unpacked and packed. Hence the question. Also why would python be a system variable? It should be part of the PATH and depending on how Tomcat is run it does know of the PATH or not.

Comment: Python is already added to the environment variables path. It is not a system variable. Sorry for theat.When I run python from command prompt it is recognized. However python is not recognized within the tomcat servlet container. How would I make tomcat recognize the python path.

Comment: I assume it runs as a background service, that PATH is only available in the command line. You will need to explicitly set it for the process. You are on windows and I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: When running python scripts from java you must provide the full python executable path. For some reason tomcat does not recognize the system variables.

A better updated solution is to write a python(preferably flask) based http application and serve it using waitress(a python library).